# Show div if user comes from certain page

Tags: jquery

I want to show a modal if user clicks "Return to merchant's page" from PayPal. i tried doing this but it doesn't work.

```
if(document.referrer:contains('paypal.com')){
    jQuery('#generosity').fadeIn();
  }
```

Comment: where is the problem? did you check that if block is hitting?What document.referrer returns you in console?

Comment: returns nothing in the console.

Comment: are you sure with this block `document.referrer:contains`?

Comment: @FadhlyPermata no

Comment: @RazvanCuceu: Check my answer below...

Comment: @FadhlyPermata I did. Seems that something is wront with `document.referrer.include('paypal')`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is up to the server side code to take care of the referrer check. And if it comes from PayPal,  you send a response where the view displays the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Refers from [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp), you can use `include` method for string object.
So, you can change your script into

```
if (document.referrer.include('paypal.com')){
    jQuery('#generosity').fadeIn();
}
```

**OR**

```
if(document.referrer.indexOf('paypal.com') != -1){
    jQuery('#generosity').fadeIn();
}
```